# Error: Could not find the correct Provider<ApiService> above this LoginPage Widget

Tags: flutter, chopper

Hi I am Trying to call a POST api using chopper. but it is giving me

"Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this LoginPage Widget".

Even I have added the provider as the ancestor widget to the page.

What am I doing wrong? please help.

```
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Provider(
  create: (_) => ApiService.create(),
  dispose: (context, ApiService service) => service.client.dispose(),
  child: Container(
                          width: double.infinity,
                          child: ButtonTheme(
                            height: 36.0,
                            child: RaisedButton(
                              onPressed: () async {
                                //Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "/myjourney");
                                print("Arpit: ${_emailController.text + " " +_passwordController.text}");
                                generateMd5(_passwordController.text);
                                String email = _emailController.text;
                                String password = generateMd5(_passwordController.text);
                                 final response = await Provider.of<ApiService>(context)
                                  .doLogin("d1d2fe0514f7d5c748c0e7e085b36f74",email,password,"App");
                              print(response.body);
                              },
                              color: Colors.white,
                              disabledColor: Colors.white,
                              shape: BeveledRectangleBorder(),
                              textColor: Colors.indigo,
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              splashColor: Color(0xFF6c60e4),
                              child: Text("SIGN IN", style: TextStyle(
                                  fontFamily: "Montserrat",
                                  fontSize: 15.0,
                                  color: Colors.indigo,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                            ),
                          )
                      ),
);
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error because you aren't putting the `Provider` above the `Login Page` that needs it.

You have to put any `Provider` you are using above any Widget that uses it. This process is called `Lifting state up`.

To correct the error, remove the `Provider` widget from the `Login` Widget and wrap it in the root widget of your application.

Like the code below:

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    Provider(
    create: (_) => ApiService.create(),
    dispose: (context, ApiService service) => service.client.dispose(),      
    child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}
```

To read more about lifting state up. Check the link below:

[Using provider correctly](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple)

I hope this helps.

Comment: I will accept your answer. what I did is I created a stateless widget and returned a provider where its child was a statefulWidget widget. then it worked perfect.

Comment: Yeah, it is the same logic. You are still placing it above the login page. Do you get ?

Answer (score 0):

you could use a Consumer below to avoid using the wrong context:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Provider(
    create: (_) => Foo(),
    child: Consumer<Foo>(
      builder: (_, foo, __) => Text(foo.value),
    },
  );
}
```

Like this:

```
@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Provider<ApiService>(
  create: (_) => ApiService.create(),
  dispose: (context, ApiService service) => service.client.dispose(),
  child: Consumer<ApiService>(
          builder: (_, apiService, __) => Container(
                          width: double.infinity,
                          child: ButtonTheme(
                            height: 36.0,
                            child: RaisedButton(
                              onPressed: () async {
                                //Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "/myjourney");
                                print("Arpit: ${_emailController.text + " " +_passwordController.text}");
                                generateMd5(_passwordController.text);
                                String email = _emailController.text;
                                String password = generateMd5(_passwordController.text);
                                 final response = await apiService.doLogin("d1d2fe0514f7d5c748c0e7e085b36f74",email,password,"App");
                              print(response.body);
                              },
                              color: Colors.white,
                              disabledColor: Colors.white,
                              shape: BeveledRectangleBorder(),
                              textColor: Colors.indigo,
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              splashColor: Color(0xFF6c60e4),
                              child: Text("SIGN IN", style: TextStyle(
                                  fontFamily: "Montserrat",
                                  fontSize: 15.0,
                                  color: Colors.indigo,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                            ),
                          )
                      ),
);
```

Check COnsumer documentation here:
https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/Consumer-class.html